# Org mode make an inactive todo item active on a specific date

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'm using org mode to keep track of my schoolwork at university right now, a feature I really like is being able to schedule recurring items since many classes have homework be due on the same day of each week. What I'm wondering is, is it possible to specify when a todo item becomes "activated" or shows up in my agenda?

For example, one of my classes has a quiz that's due every Friday but it only gets released every Monday. What I'd love to do is somehow program a todo item that's due on one day (an upcoming Friday for example) but remains "inactive" until the Monday so it's not cluttering my agenda on days where working on it is impossible. I've heard that the way Org mode would have us think about scheduled items isn't strictly intuitive but I'm hoping there's a feature somewhere for this use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you write

```
* TODO Quiz
  DEADLINE: <2020-10-09 -5d>
```

on, Monday 2020-10-05, you should get some thing like

```
  task:       In   4 d.:  TODO Quiz
```

in your agenda. Note that this will only appear on Monday.  If on Sunday you look at the agenda for the next day, this entry will not appear.